# JS pop up form with HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, popup

My page is: http://www2.leicabiosystems.com/l/48532/2018-02-16/693471i

I have coded a JS/CSS/HTML pop up form on the first "download the brochure" button

```
<button id="popup" onclick="div_show()">Download the brochure</button>
```

when I click on the button, the pop up form opens in the container and the button is usable only once.

My questions:

1. How can I extract the pop up form from the container, to have it on full width on the page? on overlay mode
2. How can I use it multiple times throughout the page? so the user can click on it multiple times and be able to see it whenever he clicks on it. for him not to scroll up or down to retrieve the pop up form.

Comment: You probably need some "modal" kind of thing. Which interacts with UI easily without blocking user's action.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question. Please also limit the post to one question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
     
     $("#click").click(function(){
     $(".popup").show();
     });      
     });
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
    .popup{position: fixed; top:35%; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1050; display: none;  outline: 0;overflow: auto;}

    .popup .popup_width{width: 500px;}
    .popup .controls_width{width: 450px;}
    .popup .color{width: max-content; padding-bottom: 0px;margin-right: 10px;}
    .popup .removeborder{border:none;}
    .popup .footerview {display: inline-block;}
    .popup .footercontrol{list-style-type: none; display: flex; width:100%; padding: 0;}
    .popup .footercontrol li{padding-right: 10px;}
    .popup .footercontrol .dropdown-menu .delete_note{margin:auto;}
    .popup .footercontrol li:last-child{margin-left: 290px; padding: 0;}
    </style>
    <input type="submit" id="click"/>
    <div class="popup" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                    <!-- Modal content-->
                    <div class="modal-content popup_width">
                        <form method="post" class="" name="frm" id="existingnote">
                            <div class="modal-header removeborder">
                                <div class="form-group controls_width">
                                    <input type="text" name="title"  class="form-control" id="exsistitle">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body removeborder">
                                <div class="form-group controls_width">
                                    <textarea name="desc" class="form-control " id="exsistxtarea" ></textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer removeborder footerview">

                                <!--              <div class="form-group ">-->
                                <ul class="footercontrol" type="none">
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="color ">
                                            <input type='text' id="color_selecter" class="basic curr_bgcolor" />
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <div class="dropdown footercontrol">
                                            <!--<i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v" style="font-size: 25px;" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown"></i>-->
                                            <span class="fas fa-ellipsis-v" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown"></span>
                                            <!--<span class="caret" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown"></span>-->
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                                                <li role="presentation" class="delete_note"><a href="#">Delete note</a></li>

                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                    <!--<input type="color" name="favcolor" id="color_selecter" value="#ffffff">-->
                                    <li><input type="submit" name="title" placeholder="Title" class="form-control btn btn-primary" id="save_changes_btn" value="Done"></li>
                                </ul>
                                <!--              </div>-->
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>




.popup{position: fixed; top:35%; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1050; display: none;  outline: 0;overflow: auto;}

.popup .popup_width{width: 500px;}
.popup .controls_width{width: 450px;}
.popup .color{width: max-content; padding-bottom: 0px;margin-right: 10px;}
.popup .removeborder{border:none;}
.popup .footerview {display: inline-block;}
.popup .footercontrol{list-style-type: none; display: flex; width:100%; padding: 0;}
.popup .footercontrol li{padding-right: 10px;}
.popup .footercontrol .dropdown-menu .delete_note{margin:auto;}
.popup .footercontrol li:last-child{margin-left: 290px; padding: 0;}

js:
$(".popup").show();
$(".popup").hide();
```